# Running Tracert command 140 times in 1 command with different hosts

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So i want to run the tracert command, but my problem is that the destination changes (tracert world1.runescape.com > tracert world140.runescape.com )

So my question is, how do i add the variable so it will change from 1 all the way to 140.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code :

```
@echo off
for /l %%# in (1,1,140) do (
echo TraceRoute for world%%#.runescape.com
echo.
    Tracert world%%#.runescape.com
)
pause
```

And if you like to store the result into a text file :

```
@echo off
Color 0A & Mode con cols=80 lines=3
Set LogFile=Traceroute.txt
If Exist %LogFile% Del %LogFile%
for /l %%# in (1,1,140) do (
echo TraceRoute for world%%#.runescape.com
Cls
Title Tracert world%%#.runescape.com
echo(
echo       Please Wait... TraceRoute to world%%#.runescape.com in progress...
    Tracert world%%#.runescape.com >> %LogFile%
)
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

So you are looking to keep doing tracert 140 times. This code might help but It keeps on going until you close the batch file. Good Luck!!!

```
          tracert world140.runescape.com
          call tracert.bat
```

When you did the code, save the batch file as tracert.bat and open it. It will keep on going untill you close the window. Enjoy and Please Like!!!

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question.  The question is asking how to tracert 140 times, but also how to change the network address string to include the iteration number in the string.